# Seeking Guidance on Implementing HighCharts in Joomla

Tags: joomla, highcharts

We want to implement HighCharts in our custom Joomla module.  Since it's a Javascript library, do we attach it to the view as a reference to the script files?  I've also read about a PHP wrapper for HighCharts.  Is it advisable to use it instead of the direct Javascript library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To embed Javascript files into a Joomla module, you need to use the following code:

```
$document =& JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript(JURI::root() . "modules/mod_your_module/file.js");
$document->addScript(JURI::root() . "modules/mod_your_module/file2.js");
...
```

If you need to write custom Javascript, then you will need to write it like so:

```
$js = 'alert("alert message");';
$document->addScriptDeclaration($js);
```

Hope this helps.