# Joomla PHP file

Tags: php, joomla, upload, joomla1.5

I have a PHP file, which uses jquery and other, It uploads the image to upload folder , I want to use the same structure to my joomla 1.5 site. I am not sure how can I get this working in side a module . I tried taking all the file with default joomla module structure but I could not see more than the title of my joomla module . Not sure If I am missing something . Please guide me how I can take this to my site ?

img : https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yk0h.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We firstly you will need to create a basic Joomla module structure as you will see in the default Joomla module such as "Login". Seeing as you have only provided a screenshot of the files and folders you're using, I am limited to what I can provide you.

So the first link is this:

http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_simple_module

It shows you how to create a simple module and after that, have a search on Google for other tutorials.

Also, if you don't want to create you own module, you could always use a pre made one from the [Joomla Extensions Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/).

Comment: Thanks Lodder, I will follow your instruction and let you know, but I am wondering how can I include other files with my module as you can see some in "JS" folder. .
Let me tell you what I want to achieve, I want to improve the image upload in my Joomgallery using some of the AJAX-PHP-Jquery projects . So fist I thought I'll get working as a module then will call Upload class of Joomgallery from my Module so that I can do image upload from any page . Any pointers in this direction is appreciated .

Comment: To include JS files in your module, you can use the code I provided in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770484/seeking-guidance-on-implementing-highcharts-in-joomla/12772066#12772066